# Why do I see None elements when I use enumerate with comprehension expressions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example, there is `[None, None, None]` element when I use list comprehension:

```
[print(i,v) for i,v in enumerate([1, 2, 3])]
0 1
1 2
2 3
[None, None, None]
```

But with usual `for` cycle there is no `[None, None, None]` element:

```
for i,v in enumerate([1, 2, 3]):
  print(i,v)
0 1
1 2
2 3

list(enumerate([1, 2, 3]))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything. You usually want to use list comprehensions to hold the output of different functions or expressions. You don't want to use them on things like print that only have side effects

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: print returns None

Comment: The list-comprehension is capturing the result of calling `print` - the value or object returned by `print` - which is `None`. As a side-effect of calling `print(i, v)`, the contents of `i` and `v` are displayed, but not captured in the list-comprehension. In addition, this has nothing to do with `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[print(x) for x in ...]
```

This creates a list that is composed of the *return value* of calling `print()` over and over.

But `print()` returns None.  Yes, it displays things on the screen, but the actual *return value* is None.

Therefore your list has a bunch of Nones in it.